# XeLaTeX can find font, but xdvipdfmx can't

Tags: fonts, xetex, opentype

I had hoped to use the Minion and Myriad fonts from my new copy of Adobe CS 5 in XeLaTeX; but `\setmainfont{Minion Pro}` produces the following error: (output of `xdvipdfmx -vvv` shown)

> DVI File Info
>   Unit: 25400000 / 473628672
>   Magnification: 1000
>   Media Height: 41484288
>   Media Width: 26673152
>   Stack Depth: 3
>   Page count:         1
>   DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2010.08.20:1057
>   DVI file font info
>   TeX Font: MinionPro-Regular loaded at ID=   16, size= 9.96pt (scaled 100.0%)
>   tufte.xdv -> tufte.pdf
>    D:/TEMP/dvipdfmx.a0056400001 [1
>   ** ERROR ** Cannot proceed without the "native" font: MinionPro-Regular (Minion Pro Regular)...
>   Output file removed.

Variations of the argument, such as `MinionPro`, `MinionPro-Regular`, `Minion Pro Regular`, etc., also produce the error. Refreshing the font cache, with `fc-cache -fv`, doesn't change anything either.

I have determined that it is the output driver, xdvipdfmx, that is causing this error, since invoking xelatex with `--no-pdf` works without any problems. Apparently XeLaTeX can find the font, but the output driver can't.

To make things even more bizarre, if I select the font like this:

```
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation,%
 BoldFont=MinionPro-Bold.otf,%
 ItalicFont=MinionPro-It.otf,%
 BoldItalicFont=MinionPro-BoldIt.otf]{MinionPro-Regular.otf}
```

everything works as expected. Can somebody advise me as to what is going on here?

**UPDATE**: I changed above to show the output of `xdvipdfmx -vvv`.

Comment: I’ve got the same problem with TeX Gyre Pagella. A bit of googling reveals that quite a few people seem to be having this problem. Incidentally, using the (deprecated, I understand?) `xdv2pdf` instead of `xdvipdfmx` works so this is may point to a bug in the latter driver.

Comment: FWIW: I had the same problem on Mac OS X, and the fix was to move the fonts from my local directory (`~/Library/Fonts`) to the system directory (`/Library/Fonts`). Thanks to Khaled's comment on his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An update to TeX Live 2010 solved the problem for me. Apparently, [this is a problem specific to XeTeX 0.9996](http://www.macfreek.nl/mindmaster/LaTeX_package_conflicts#Invalid_Font_Description).

Comment: I ran into this issue yesterday with one of my fonts, today I can't reproduce it. I'm not sure what solved it, but cleared my fontconfig cache several times in between (I'm on Linux), also the font itself were slightly changed. So, I'd first try to clear system font cache and see.

Comment: I can confirm that upgrading to 2010 solved my problem too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running xdvipdfmx on the XDV file with ascending verbosity levels, -v, -vv, -vvv etc. probably you will be able identify some possible cause.

Comment: See update to question - still stumped, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have the font installed on the system i.e. you can access it with system applications? The fact that the font can be loaded by file name and not by font name is likely to mean that you have installed the font in your TEXMF tree. Unfortunately, XeTeX can't find fonts in the TEXMF tree by font name, you have to install the fonts system wide for this to work (and when doing so, don't forget to delete the TEXMF copy as its co-existence can cause other problems).

As a side note (a bit of advocating one's own work), LuaLaTeX in texlive2010 can load fonts by font name either way.

Comment: Yes, it's installed on the system, and not in the TEXMF tree. It seems that XeTeX can find the font just fine (since it complains when I replace `Minion Pro` with a nonsense font name), it's xdvipdfmx that can't find it.